# site subdirectory acts as root dir? Should I redirect 301 permanent?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have the following problem - my site is located one folder below the /www folder on my hosting account, let's say its /www/shop. All the visitors that come to the main domain are then redirected by .htaccess file in the /www folder which takes them to the subfolder.

Should I make this redirect 301 Permanent, so that search engines could index my site better?
Here's the simple .htaccess that I use for the purpose:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /shop [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's really permanent, yes.

Comment: What would happen if it is permanently in the subfolder and I leave the .htaccess without 301 redirection? Search engines would think that my site is in the root dir and won't index it properly or ... what else?

Comment: @Ilian Andreev: I think that they would check the redirect more often.